# Vuejs : How to display array value like this

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I want to display the values in the day object such as: Sunday, Monday, etc.

[image]

For now, here my code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" v-for="item in result" v-bind:key="item.schedule_id">
    {{ item.day }}
</div>
```

My result:

```
[ "Monday", "Wednesday" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do another loop as

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" v-for="item in result" v-bind:key="item.schedule_id">
       <div v-for="(day , index) in item.day" :key="index">
        {{day}}
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But, for the result, how to retain the comma?

Comment: you can add comma after {{day}} like {{day}} ,

Comment: I actually want the commas to be between the arrays, but even this is fine, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want just return the days use the `flatMap` function :

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" v-for="day in result.flatMap(item=>item.day)" v-bind:key="day">
    {{ day }}
</div>
```

if you want to separate them by comma use this :

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"  >
    {{ result.flatMap(item=>item.day).join(',') }}
</div>
```

or between arrays:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"  >
    {{ result.map(item=>item.day).join(',') }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a better and easy solution

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" v-for="item in result" :key="item.schedule_id"> {{ item.day.join(',') }} </div>
```